# Swift: Get little strips, when add a border to UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift

When i add a border to a UIImageView, i get little black strips on the following picture. I try my app on a real iPhone and i can see the little strips too. How can i remove this or where is the issue of this?

Anyone have an idea?

[image]

Here is my code for the UIImageView:

```
//Setup ProfileImageView
    profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.frame.size.width / 2
    profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    profileImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    profileImageView.layer.borderWidth = 4.0
    profileImageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.12
    profileImageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
    profileImageView.layer.shadowRadius = 2
    profileImageView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
```

And my Storyboard Settings:

[image]

I use the Xcode 10 beta 6... Could that be a problem?

Comment: Do you mean the black border around the edge of the screenshot?

Comment: no i mean the little black border around the round Image inside the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the image is bleeding out of the layer's borders when you set the `cornerRadius`. See this post: [iOS: Rounded rectangle with border bleeds color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565736/ios-rounded-rectangle-with-border-bleeds-color)

The `CAShapeLayer` solution that was suggested by @FelixLam in the aforementioned post could be something like this:

```
let lineWidth: CGFloat = 4.0 // the width of the white border that you want to set
let imageWidth = self.profileImageView.bounds.width
let imageHeight = self.profileImageView.bounds.height

// make sure width and height are same before drawing a circle
if (imageWidth == imageHeight) {
    let side = imageWidth - lineWidth
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath.init(ovalIn: CGRect(lineWidth / 2, lineWidth / 2, side, side))

    // add a new layer for the white border
    let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    borderLayer.path = circularPath.CGPath
    borderLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
    borderLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    self.profileImageView.layer.insertSublayer(borderLayer, at: 0)

    // set the circle mask to your profile image view
    let circularMask = CAShapeLayer()
    circularMask.path = circularPath.CGPath
    self.profileImageView.layer.mask = circularMask
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. When i add this code to my project, i get the following error in this line: "let side = imageWidth - lineWidth": Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'CGFloat' and 'Double' How can i solve the compiler issue?

Comment: It’s probably because of the first line. By default the `lineWidth` is going to be declared as Double. Fix it by changing to `let lineWidth: CGFloat = 4.0`. Anyway, I’ll update my answer as well